# How to make the subscript in $f(x)_{x \to x_0} \to \lambda$ appear beneath the arrow

Tags: math-mode

Sometimes I like to write my limits in the form

> ```
> f(x) ----> a
>
>    x --> 0
> ```

Is there a way to achieve that in latex ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are certainly several different possibilities to achieve this. One is provided by the [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package which you might use anyway. Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[ f(x) \xrightarrow[x \rightarrow 0]{} a \]
\end{document}
```

Have a look at page 13 of the [documentation of the package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) to find out more.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Certainly. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
f\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}a.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]